# Using survey design (from srvyr) on long dataset

Tags: dplyr

I have a dataset with hundreds of thousands of rows. I need to convert the data to long format and use a survey design to summarise the data.

I'm providing an example but was unable to replicate the error.

```
library(dplyr)
library(srvyr)

df <- data.frame(
  a=as.character(rnorm(1000, 5, 2)),
  b=rep(c("a","b"), 1000),
  c=rep(c("aa","bb"), 1000),
  strata = rep(rnorm(100, 1000, 1000), 10),
  weight = abs(rnorm(1000, 1, 2))
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = a:c,
    names_to = "key",
    values_to = "value") %>%
  # create design object
  as_survey_design(strata=strata, weights=weight)
```

On my full data, I get the following error which disappears when I remove the strata variable. Any insight into what might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rowSums': attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

Note: my strata variable has ~ 2700 levels, with n's ranging from 1-2600.

Edit: I was able to reproduce the error with a large dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a=as.character(rnorm(15000000, 5, 2)),
  b=rep(c("a","b"), 15000000),
  c=rep(c("aa","bb"), 15000000),
  strata = rep(rnorm(100, 1000, 1000), 150000),
  weight = abs(rnorm(15000000, 1, 2))
) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = a:c,
    names_to = "key",
    values_to = "value") %>%
  # create design object
  as_survey_design(strata=strata, weights=weight)

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rowSums': attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is due to the size of your data frame, which exceeds the limit of 2^31 elements that R can handle. This limit is reached when you generate a large number of random values using rnorm() and repeat them multiple times.

To solve this, you may want to consider using alternative methods or libraries that can handle big data, such as `bigmemory` or `data.table`. These libraries provide efficient data structures and algorithms for working with large datasets in R.

Test the following code, using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# Create a data.table object
dt <- data.table(
  a = as.character(rnorm(15000000, 5, 2)),
  b = rep(c("a", "b"), 15000000),
  c = rep(c("aa", "bb"), 15000000),
  strata = rep(rnorm(100, 1000, 1000), 150000),
  weight = abs(rnorm(15000000, 1, 2))
)

# Pivot the data using data.table
dt_pivot <- melt(dt, measure.vars = c("a", "b", "c"), variable.name = "key", value.name = "value")

# Create the design object
dt_design <- svydesign(
  formula = ~1,
  data = dt_pivot,
  strata = ~strata,
  weights = ~weight
)
```

You can learn more about the `data.table` library [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html), and for the `bigmemory`, you can access [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html). Take a look at the reference manual in the documentation section.